# How to move images around a circle with javascript, style and HTML

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am new in HTML, style sheet and Javascript. I created this
(change image reference)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:100px;
}

.block, .center
{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
    background:#5aa;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-12%;
    margin-top:-12%;
}

.center
{
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    margin-left:-15%;
    margin-top:-15%;
    border-radius:100%;
}

.tl
{
    left:20%;
    top:20%;
}
.tr
{
    left:80%;
    top:20%;
}
.br
{
    left:80%;
    top:80%;
}
.bl
{
    left:20%;
    top:80%;
}
.t
{
    top:10%;
}
.r
{
    left:90%;
}
.b
{
    top:90%;
}
.l
{
    left:10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block tl">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block t">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block tr">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block l">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="center">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block r">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block bl">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block b">
    <img src="painting\afremov_flower_ (1).jpg" class="block br">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to move boxes around the circle present in center. How is it possible?
As you can see I have not use any canvas so is it possible without any canvas creation?
Because I got some code from this site but they are all with canvas.

Thanks for your help and time.

Rana

Answer (score 4):

Basically this is how you could do it:

**The Javascript**

```
function drawCircle(selector, center, radius, angle, x, y) {
  var total = $(selector).length;
  var alpha = Math.PI * 2 / total;
  angle *= Math.PI / 180;

  $(selector).each(function(index) {
    var theta = alpha * index;
    var pointx  =  Math.floor(Math.cos( theta + angle ) * radius);
    var pointy  = Math.floor(Math.sin( theta + angle ) * radius );

    $(this).css('margin-left', pointx + x + 'px');
    $(this).css('margin-top', pointy + y + 'px');
  });
}
```

**The CSS**

```
.container { 
  width:800px; margin:0 auto;
}

.box {    
  -moz-border-radius:150px;
  -webkit-border-radius:150px;
  background-position:0px 0px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:left;
  height:120px;
  margin:18px;
  position:absolute;
  width:120px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

**The HTML markup**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box">
</div>
```

See [DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/ixisav/9/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost correct, you forget to convert degrees to radians for cos/sin. If you add `angle *= Math.PI / 180;` inside the `drawCircle()` function it will work perfect. +1 from me. http://jsbin.com/adeleb/1/edit

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware, thanks a lot, added your improvemnt, now it rotates nicely and looks almost like a 'revolving drum' :)

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer, nice article, I knew already most of the indicators of that behaviour, but didn't know there is a term for it. In this case let's say I forgot my garlic collar, so I got bitten :) It made me feel also a bit nostalgic by the frase *am new in HTML, style sheet and Javascript* and it remembered me of my early day's back in the late 90's when there was no such community as today...

Comment: above suggestion is OK, but it's not fulfilling my wish. actually I want that every image will move in circular path. But suggested code placing the images in circular path.

Comment: @rana, why not? it moves the images in a circular path, to do so the images need to be placed also in a circular path, makes sense?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I cant show you the image that i am getting because I dont have 10 reputation point.      I run your code in tomcat 7.0 server which i am using and I got all the images placed in circular path only. they are not moving. I understand that to do so the images need to be placed also in a circular path.

Comment: @rans, the images are not moving because you need to call the `drawCircle` javascript function you can see above. in the example I've added to my answer they get moved by pressing a button, but I guess in your case you have to call the mehtod yourself, but without seeing your code it will be up to you to do so...